probabilistic method for determining the maximal vector modulus
I got some trouble in the following question:
$v_1,\cdots, v_n\in \mathbf{R}^n$, $\|v_i\|_2\leq 1$ for any $1\leq i \leq n$.
Then let $w=\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_iv_i,$ $\quad \forall p_i\in[0,1].$
I need to show that for any fixed $w$, $\exists \epsilon_1,\cdots, \epsilon_n\in\{0,1\},\text{such that } \|w-\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i v_i\|\leq\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}.$
I'm required to use the probability method to prove it, but I don't even know where should I begin. I try to finish it with some linear algebra acknowledge, such as translating $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n$ into orthonormal basis. It doesn't work.
I'm a beginner for probability, so if you can, please show me some important probability methods. Any help is welcome.
